# Error: Unrecognized base64 character

Tags: callout, httprequest, character-encoding

Hey I am trying to get the access token to GA from Salesforce but following the execution it gives me the following error:

> System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character: -

This is the current code that I am using:

```
  public class getAccessToken {



    public  getAccessToken()
    {
        system.debug(getToken());
    }



public String getToken(){

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
req.setMethod('POST');

req.setHeader('ContentType','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

String header = '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';
String header_encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(header));

String claim_set = '{"iss":"[my gmail account]"';
claim_set += ',"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"';
claim_set += ',"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"';
claim_set += ',"exp":"' + datetime.now().addHours(1).getTime()/1000;
claim_set += '","iat":"' + datetime.now().getTime()/1000 + '"}';

String claim_set_encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(claim_set));

String signature_encoded = header_encoded + '.' + claim_set_encoded;

String key = '[my key]';

blob private_key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key);
signature_encoded = signature_encoded.replaceAll('=','');
String signature_encoded_url = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signature_encoded,'UTF-8');
blob signature_blob =   blob.valueof(signature_encoded_url);

String signature_blob_string = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', signature_blob, private_key));

String JWT = signature_encoded + '.' + signature_blob_string;

JWT = JWT.replaceAll('=','');

String grant_string= 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer';
req.setBody('grant_type=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(grant_string, 'UTF-8') + '&assertion=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JWT, 'UTF-8'));
res = h.send(req);
String response_debug = res.getBody() +' '+ res.getStatusCode();
System.debug('Response =' + response_debug );
if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'access_token')) {
            // Move to the value.
            parser.nextToken();
            // Return the access_token
            return parser.getText();
        }
    }
}
return 'error';

}

}
```

Comment: In which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Hi Marc, I rolled back your edit as it changed the question after Lex had posted an answer to the original one. Could you post the new question as a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to decode the (supposedly) base64-encoded string `key`, somewhere halfway through the code. However, in your sample, the string is hardcoded to `[my key]`, probably because you don't want to post your actual key (good idea).

Probably in your code, there's a `-` in there somewhere. Base64 encoded strings only contain letters, numbers and the characters `+` and `\` (and `=` for padding).